# Significant increase in file size (x10) after applying function on NetCDF data using xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, era5

I am working on [ERA5 reanalysis data](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=overview) in NetCDF format, and I need to compute wind direction based on U and V components.

I already have a working piece of Python code to do so using xarray and pandas, and saving output as NetCDF.

While I do not add any additional data (only applying transformation to compute a new variable instead of U and V), I'm getting a huge increase in the size of the ouput file.
Input files are about 30 Mo and the output one is about 300 Mo.

Can someone explain what is going on ? There must be something with the way my output file is being shaped, but I don't get how. Is it due to the encoding of the file, datatype used (float32 in both input and output here), or any other NetCDF format issue ?

Also, do you have any idea how I could optimize the size of the output file ?

To help you understand the differences, here is a summary of the input file :

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (latitude: 7, longitude: 8, time: 113952)
Coordinates:
    number      int64 ...
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 ... 1991-12-31T23:00:00
    step        timedelta64[ns] ...
    surface     float64 ...
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 47.5 47.25 47.0 46.75 46.5 46.25 46.0
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 -3.0 -2.75 -2.5 -2.25 -2.0 -1.75 -1.5 -1.25
    valid_time  (time) datetime64[ns] ...
Data variables:
    u10         (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            1
    GRIB_centre:             ecmf
    GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    history:                 2022-05-04T13:10 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.9...
```

And the output one :

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (latitude: 7, longitude: 8, time: 113952)
Coordinates:
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 ... 1991-12-31T23:00:00
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 46.0 46.25 46.5 46.75 47.0 47.25 47.5
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 -3.0 -2.75 -2.5 -2.25 -2.0 -1.75 -1.5 -1.25
Data variables:
    number      (time, latitude, longitude) int64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0
    step        (time, latitude, longitude) timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00 ... 00:0...
    surface     (time, latitude, longitude) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0
    valid_time  (time, latitude, longitude) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 ... 199...
    direction   (time, latitude, longitude) float32 17.76 26.89 ... 180.1 178.5
```

Only difference I can see is that some of the original coordinates are now data variables.

Comment: this is a common thing to encounter when working with Datasets, so I threw some general advice into an answer. but to get specific help, we'd definitely need to see some code, esp as a [mre]. thanks!

Comment: As a first check, I would check the shape of all NetCDF variables, in both cases (with vs without xarray). But the answer here explains it in detail

Comment: first up, ERA5 data is packed (stored as 2 byte shorts with an offset and scale factor) but that would only explain a factor of two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly, all your variables are now indexed by `(time, latitude, longitude)`, so will have the full array size of `(7 x 8 x 113952)`. Previously, `number`, `step`, and `surface` were scalars (not an array - just a single value), and `valid_time` was only indexed by `time`.  Since all of these are 64-bit, your new array now has effectively 4 new variables each of which are twice the size as `u10`. So that alone accounts for a 9x increase.

To ensure this doesn't happen, try being really careful to only do math & reshape operations with DataArrays, not Datasets. Xarray works perfectly well when working with Datasets, but the behavior isn't always intuitive when you're just getting the hang of it, and automatic broadcasting like this is one of the things that can catch you off guard. I always recommend that people do their work with DataArrays and then create a Dataset before write for this reason. See the docs on [Broadcasting by dimension name](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#broadcasting-by-dimension-name) and [Automatic Alignment](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#automatic-alignment) for more on this topic.

I'd also expect that if you got this data from ECMWF the source data may be compressed on disk, which is not the default for [`ds.to_netcdf`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf.html). See the docs on [writing netCDFs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html#netcdf) for a discussion of compression options.

Comment: Definitely helpful answer, thank you ! I now feel like I didn't understand how my multi-dimensional arrays were shaped in the first place…

Comment: I thought that for each element of my final array, I just had a tuple (with additional variables) instead of a scalar : didn't get that each initial coordinate now take place as a full dimensional array !
Also, thanks for the advice on manipulating DataArrays instead of DataSets. I'll look forward into that and come back to SO if I need help on how to rewrite my Python/Pandas code to optimize the computation.